# Use writetable inside loop in matlab

Tags: matlab, loops, assign, names

I'm trying to use writetable command inside a loop. Any help?

Comment: Why did you completely empty the question ? Now people reading the answer have no way to understand how it can be useful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MonthNames=['JAN'; 'FEB'; 'MAR'; 'APR'; 'MAY'; 'JUN'; 'JUL'; 'AUG'; 'SEP'; 'OCT'; 'NOV'; 'DEC'];
for sensorIndex = 1:numel(sensor)
    for monthIndex = 1:numel(MonthNames)
        % Get the current sensor
        k = sensor(sensorIndex);

        % Get the file(s?) associated with that sensor
        S = dir(fullfile(path, '*', sprintf('sensor%d.xls', k));

        % Create an output filename
        filename = sprintf('sensor%d_%s.xls', k, MonthNames(monthIndex));
        
        % do your stuff
        F = fullfile(S(k).folder,S(k).name);
        data = readtable(F);
        writetable(data, filename);
    end
end
```

Doing it this way lets you optionally not have ALL months. Lots of ways to code it, but my personal preference is to keep loop variables as indices and grab the current variable inside the loop using that index.

Comment: @mathew81 put it in the loop, where I wrote `% do your stuff`. Otherwise you've got to cache and recover the filenames, but then you're just looping later to iterate across the cached filenames. Just do everything in the loop.

Comment: Ι'm confused with the syntax of the writetable command.

Comment: @mathew81 I'm confused how your code appears to append all sensor data to one `out` variable and then writes that to the last sensor's January xls file. In the code I provided, you would call `writetable(out, filename);` where it says `% do your stuff`, but you should also put some data into `out` before you do that. In your example it looks like you're just reading tables and then writing those same tables back so unfortunately I can't give you any advice on what to modify there.

Comment: perhaps the writetable command should be inside the loop but with an indicator to change the sensor (like 'sensor'(ci).'_January.xls'). This is the part that I need help.

Comment: @mathew81 - I edited the answer to try to incorporate your code, but hopefully this is making it clear to you that the code you posted doesn't really show us what you're trying to do. It looks like you're loading a file and then writing that file. If the `S = dir` portion is supposed to pull multiple files then you'd need to iterate across those files, so you'd have a third loop inside like `for fileIndex = 1:numel(S)` and then `currentFile = S(fileIndex)`, basically, and you could do your `out = [out; data]`, but I don't know what you're trying to do so this is the best I can help.

Comment: the above code works fine but the name of the files created with the xlswrite command are sensor1A, sensor1B...sensor5E etc. So something needs to be fixed in  filename = sprintf('sensor%d_%s.xls', k, MonthNames(monthIndex)); line. Thank you for your time!

Comment: @mathew81 - You haven't provided a definition for the `sensor` vector, but if you'd like to use the sensor index instead of whatever you have as the sensor name then replace `k` with `sensorIndex` in the `sprintf` command. If your sensor names are strings and not numbers then honestly I'm surprised the `%d` formatting is giving you anything.